# foreach duplicate include in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to include some headers using Makefile.

Here's the code I did:

```
# Add .h and .hpp to the preprocessor build
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/*.h)
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/*.hpp)
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/**/*.h)
HEADERS += $(wildcard src/**/*.hpp)
INCLUDES = $(foreach HEADERS, $(HEADERS), -I$(dir $(HEADERS)))

# FLAGS will be passed to both the C and C++ compiler
FLAGS +=
CFLAGS +=
CXXFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
```

But once I build, that's what it execute:

```
g++  -Isrc/  -Isrc/  -Isrc/  -Isrc/misc/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/  -Isrc/widgets/ -Wsuggest-override -std=c++11  -DSLUG=NWK -fPIC -I../../include -I../../dep/include -O3 -DVERSION=0.6.4 -MMD -MP -g -march=nocona -ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -DARCH_WIN -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -c -o build/src/plugins/MyPlug.cpp.o src/plugins/MyPlug.cpp
```

It seems that, for each `.h`/`.hpp` it found, it replicate the `HEADER` flag.

How would you fix it?

Comment: Did you try using `$(sort LIST)` which sorts the list *and removes duplicates*, as explained in GNU make's documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to just pass your search through `$(sort ...)`.   In make, `$(sort ...)` removes any duplicates:

```
INCLUDES = $(sort $(foreach HEADERS, $(HEADERS), -I$(dir $(HEADERS))))
```

One note -- sort does change the order of the include directories, which in turn will change the order the directories will be searched, however, the method you are using to populate your lists does not seem to be order dependent, so you should be good.